# Neural Network on an external harddrive

Tags: python, neural-network

I was wondering if anybody either had experience or suggestions regarding the
possibility of storing a neural network (nodes, synapses) on an external hard-drive, and using a computer to run it. I do not know whether this is possible.
I would like to be able to run a convolutional Neural Network while not loading my
computer up. Thanks.

Comment: I mean you could represent a net as a file, but how do you intend on running it without starting your computer up?

Comment: When you say "not loading my computer up" do you mean without having to retrain the model?

Comment: to dhdavvie: while I would be interested if that was possible, that was not what I had in mind. I was thinking about using the computer to update and pass input to the network.

Comment: to wyllie: no I intend on retraining. By 'not loading my computer up' I meant not using my computer's memory for nodes and synapses and instead using the external hard drive's memory for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A hard drive could simply store a file that represents your network. Perhaps a JSON file with the thousands of optimized weight values, etc. Or if it is optimized, simply a template on layers and neurons, depending on what you hope to do (test or train?). Then the program you have on your computer can load this file, and test/train it. The fact it is on a hard drive makes no difference.

Comment: To add to this, it sounds like the poster is worried about the neural net taking up resources on his computer. Storing the neural net on an external hard drive will not save many resources, as it will be a fairly small file since it would simply be storing a json object (assumably). Running the neural net will still take just as much CPU time and be loaded into memory, so you do not really save resources by saving it onto a hard drive.

Comment: Yes. As a general conclusion, there is no proper answer to this question, other than do what you want, it is certainly possible.